How to attach BodyComponent objects together on ContactCallbacks in Flame as magnetic force?
I am learning Flame and have tested different scenarios in Forge2D that I want to master.
But one thing that I have not found a great solution for, is how to make BodyComponents "fuse" together based on the callbacks and then have just one object instead.
Using the example: https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Components_Composability
How would I make all the balls "stick" together as one large object, instead just the color change?
Are there any good methods to eg limit the area you will stick?
In such scenario a larger circle should weigh more than smaller ones (more gravtity force on them). Is the radius the only parameter for weight?
Hopefully someone could share their experience on this.

You will have to use a joint for this, it depends a bit on how you want them to stick together which joint you should use. But if you want them to stick together completely, then you can use a WeldJoint.
Example:
void createWeldJoint(Body first, Body second, Vector2 anchor) {
  final weldJointDef = WeldJointDef()..initialize(first, second, anchor);

  createJoint(WeldJoint(weldJointDef));
}

https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/flame_forge2d%2Fjoints_WeldJoint

Thank you for the feedback spydon! I managed to get the effect pretty near what I wanted. WeldJointDef() was as expected. Ended up creating a FixtureDef() slightly larger than the object with "isSensor=true" and then set WeldJointDef().
I also needed to keep the welds in an List to retrive all Components again.
Sometimes though the object might weld in high speed making them odd placed.  Did a velocity calc to not trigger weld on high speeds, but is a "cooler" way that might bend the object based on the "magnetic field" of other objects?

You might have to set isBullet = true if you're doing high speeds

If you add two FixtureDef() to an object is there any information in the beginContact(Object other, Contact contact) to know which Fixture was triggered? Wanted to ensure that the one with isSensor=true is the only one forwarded.
